# how it will be handled if 100k requests are hit to server at a same time?

Tags: spring-mvc, web-applications

There will be one controller method for one screen but how it will be handled if multiple requests like 100 000 requests are hit at a same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple server instance and use load balancer to manage the traffic.

Comment: You are not getting my question. Consider for only 10 simultaneous requests instead of 1 lakh and tell me how it works. Hope you are clear now about what I am asking